# Flexdashboard - Open in browser chooses the port randomly

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have a flexdashboard code in R. It always opens in a new port if I launch the code. How to configure in R to open in browser in a specific port. Please help.

Comment: Please include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you're running it on the local host then this should work:

```
rmarkdown::run("shiny_doc.Rmd", shiny_args = list(port = 8241))
```

Comment: Figured that out some time back. Thanks anyways.